# Error 80048264 in windows phone

Tags: microsoft-account

I can't install any apps. I'm in need of Apps.I already clicked "I Forgot My password". I dont know my Live account password.I created a new account but can't add in my accounts. Syncing my account also doesn't work.I want to reset my phone but don't know how to.And is it 100% guaranteed that if i reset my password my store would work ? Please answer me as soon as possible .

Answer (score 1):

Basically this error occurs on two reasons:

1. When someone skips linking #Microsoft account to phone during phone setup.
2. If the #Microsoft account linked to phone is not syncing.

As per [this reference](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/winphone/forum/wp8-wpapps/error-code-80048264/bf5cf839-2d51-478f-8843-217b3b9267f2?tm=1354215069350) the only fix is to reset the phone to factory.

There is a side way, go to, settings >> email+accounts, then select the Microsoft account you used for phone setup and enter the password again. Hope it helps.

Comment: A third option is that this is a stolen phone.