# Problem during update and installation of apps on Nokia Lumia 520

Tags: lumia-520

I'm facing a problem regarding installing and updating apps on my Nokia lumia 520. It sometimes shows a store error and the code 80048264. It says sync the device to your Microsoft account.
I did that, but no results. Date and time settings are all ok.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/q/5743/106

Comment: Are you using mobile data or Wifi ??  If you are using mobile data , then Try downloading apps with a wifi connection and check whether it makes any difference..

Answer (score 0):

Just go to settings -> emails+accounts -> Enter the same password again in your main account..  This may fix the issue...